# WCF assembly causing circular dependencies

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight library which I have added a wcf service reference. Call this library A.dll. This library contains other functions and I prefer to have the wcf code in another library.

I now have created another silverlight class library which I have added the same wcf service reference (call this library B.dll) and want the first silverlight library to reference the wcf service.

If I reference A.dll in B.dll I do not get a circular reference.

I still have the wcf reference code in A.dll but with a different namespace than the wcf reference code in B.dll (not sure if this related to the problem).

Any ideas why I get this error when I reference B.dll in A.dll?

JD.

Ps. I know that I could create an interface library to provide another design but at the moment I am not sure why this error is happening.

Comment: Do you get this error as a pop-up dialog when you try to add the project B reference to project A? It is a little unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do. My understanding is that you have 2 silverlight class libraries and each has a service reference to the same WCF service. You then want one project to reference the other. I see no circular reference here as long as they both aren't trying to reference each other.

Comment: @Dan: A week ago I added the wcf service reference code to the first library. Today, I decided to put the wcf service code in another library and then reference the library from the first one. I have just removed the wcf code from the first library and I still get circular reference errors. Yes, the error is the dialog that is shown when adding the reference.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... I'm just trying to set up a new set of projects to try to repro your problem. I'm not sure if it has any effect or not but did you generate your WCF service proxy by doing Add Service Reference... or by running slsvcutil.exe and adding the generated code to the project?

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for trying. What I have done now is edit the csproj for A.dll in notepad and add B.dll to the projectReferences tag. When I now build it all works fine. However, I see a Warning Icon (triangle) in next to the referenced project (B.dll) in the solution explorer. So it looks like VS misbehaving in some way. With regards to adding the proxy, I followed Sahil Malik's excellent article (http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-7-SilverLight_WCF_References_in_SharePoint_-_The_right_way.aspx) to get the proxy without all the config baggage.

Comment: @Dan : Looks like it was VS that got in a mess. I had to manually fix the vs solution and the project file and it is all cleared up now. Not sure how it go in to this state. I created a couple of solution projects and dragged the projects into them. Not sure if that confused the ide. Anyway, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @JD: I guess looking at the Project Dependencies window of each project in your solution would have done the trick. I had the same problem. (See my comment at Mark Cooper's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I still have the wcf reference code in A.dll but with a different namespace than the wcf reference code in B.dll (not sure if this related to the problem).

I think that even though the namespaces are different, as you have already identified you have created a circular assembly reference.

VS builds dependent (referenced) assemblies first. If you ahve a circular reference, VS won't know which order to build the projects, hence the error you are getting.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the hint with the build order. I wanted to add a reference to one of my assemblies and VS was complaining about a circular reference although there was no circular depedency in the code. The problem was that I once referenced the projects the other way around and visual studio kept the depedency / reference in the Projekt Dependencies window. I hope this will help someone in the future.